# Why overriding @property accessors cause error when accessing ivar?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Why does overriding both accessors cause compilation errors when accessing the ivar `(i.e. _locked)`? If I just override the setter and not the getter, everything is fine.

I've also tried `@property(setter=setLocked:, getter=locked)` and variations of other approaches.

MyObject.h

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, assign)BOOL locked;

@end
```

MyObject.m

```
@implementation MyObject

- (void)setLocked:(BOOL)locked
{
   _locked = locked; // Error here
   // Some other logic
}


- (BOOL)locked
{
   // Some other logic
   return _locked; // Error here
}

@end
```

Comment: it doesn't autosynthesize if you specify a getter and a setter.

Comment: i saw an exact duplicate last night... cant find now

Comment: @AndrewMadsen this is definitely a duplicate. thanks. i'll delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Because in that case the compiler does not automatically synthesize an instance variable for the property and `_locked` will be undefined. Synthesize the ivar manually.

```
@implementation MyObject

@synthesize locked = _locked;

...

@end
```

Comment: +1 I think this is a better approach than explicitly declaring the ivar.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Objective-C does not require you to `@synthesize` properties: it does it when one or both accessors are missing. "Synthesizing" includes creation of one or both accessor methods, along with the ivar for storing the value of the property.

Once you override the second accessor, however, the `_locked` ivar is no longer added to your class implicitly. Therefore, you must add it yourself:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    BOOL _locked;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign)BOOL locked;

@end
```